# SQL Server recursive hierarchical query, less than optimal data structure

Tags: sql-server, recursion, hierarchical

I have a commercial application with a SQL Server 2008 R2 database that contains a table that is supposed to model a file and folder structure, similar to <root>:<sublevel 1>:<sublevel 2>..<sublevel n>:<document>. The database table contains pairs of values (folder_item, parent), where folder-item is either a document or folder, and parent is a link to another row in the table.

I am trying to write a query that returns two values per row:

- a document
- The full concatenated path to the document, from the top level folder to the immediate container of the document, for example Root:Level1:Level2..:LevelN.

Normally, a recursive query should be able to handle this situation, but there is a complication. The Folder Item table contains redundant entries for each document and sub-level, pairing them with every ancestor in the folder structure, not just their immediate parent.

Instead of
(document, parent)
(parent, grandparent)
(grandparent, great-grandparent)
...
(ancestor, root)

The table contains
(document, parent)
(document, grandparent)
...
(document, ancestor)
(document, root)
(parent, grandparent)
...
(parent, ancestor)
(parent, root)
...
(grandparent, great-grandparent)
...
(grandparent, root)

and so on. I'm sure the data modellers had their reasons for the design, but it negates the use of a standard recursive hierarchical query. In fact, when I tried, the execution exceeded the maximum number of recursion levels.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem, and can it be solved without resorting to complex programming beyond standard SQL capabilities?

Thanks much

Patrick

Comment: How about posting some table structures and sample data? If you are simply basing your recursion on the name you are likely fighting a losing battle.

Comment: The recursion is based on a unique but non-PK VARCHAR value "DOCNUMBER", where the PARENT column contains the DOCNUMBER of the ancestor row.

Comment: Fortunately, it turns out that a decision has been made to ignore the existing Folder hierarchy, and the problem has disappeared thanks to a (wise) business decision for once. Thanks to Sean and Tab for answering..

Answer (score 0):

If you've got:

> (document, parent) (document, grandparent) ... (document, ancestor)
>    (document, root)(parent, grandparent) ... (parent, ancestor) (parent, root) ... (grandparent, great-grandparent) ... (grandparent, root)

You want to limit your recursion to only:

> (document, parent)(parent, grandparent)(grandparent, great-grandparent) (great-grandparent, root)

right?  So the trick is just figuring out what condition(s) to put on the bottom half of your recursive cte, so that not EVERY relative of the current row gets joined to the current row.

So for `document`, you want `parent`.   For `parent`, you want `grandparent` and so on.  How can we create this filter?

Well for `document` what is true about `parent` that is not true about any other ancestor?

Answer:  `document` has all the same relatives as `parent` does, but only `document` has `parent` as an ancestor.

So, as you look at the parents for each folder_item, if there exists another row where that parent's parent is the same as one of the current item's parents then that folder_item is not the immediate parent of the current folder_item, and should be filtered out of the recursive join.

Picture an interview:  "So you're one of my ancestors.  If none of my other ancestors also have you as an ancestor, then you must be my immediate parent."

True, non?

I don't have your structure to test with but I'm imagining adding something like this to your recursive join would work, but it may need some tweaking...

```
{for recursion -- Join second half of UNION back to main CTE}
ON bottom.Folder_Item=cte.parent  --you are my ancestor
AND NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT * FROM MyTable mt --others
 WHERE mt.folder_item<>bottom.folder_item --the other is not you
 AND mt.Folder_Item=cte.parent --the other is also my ancestor
 AND mt.Parent=bottom.folder_item --the other also has you as ancestor
)
```

For this snippet `bottom` is my alias for the bottom half of your recursive UNION, and `cte` is the alias of the entire CTE.

And by putting this filter in the JOIN condition for recursion, I think it should prevent the recursion tree from going crazy and exceeding the recursion limit.   I **think**!

If you DO still get the recursion limit, try pre-filtering your table this way in a CTE before your recursive CTE, so you pre-eliminate all the non-immediate ancestors before doing recursion.

I think this should be able to work, but if not, you can definitely do what you need with a CURSOR.